# Internal redirection in Padrino

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

Is there a way to internally redirect in Padrino? I am writing a RESTful service, no HTML response of browser client.
I have a resource, lets say, `xyz`.

```
MyApp.controllers :xyz
```

I have two routes in a controller:

```
put :index, :with => :xyz_id do...end
```

and

```
get :show, :map => '/xyz/:xyz_id' do...end
```

Now to simplify (and centralize) view (which is a JSON document) creation, I want to just internally redirect the control so that it processes the `:show` method after creating the resource. Hence, for a client of the service, `PUT /xyz/1234` will create a new resource and return the same and `GET /xyz/1234` will return the resource if it exists.

Is there a way to INTERNALLY (not a 302 response sent to the client) redirect to `get :show` method from the `put :index` method (after creating the resource)? Something like:

```
redirect (:xyz, :index, {:xyz_id => '1234'})
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, you can put logic behind the showing data into separate function that you can call from both `GET` and `PUT` routes. If you really want to pass processing to a different route, you can do it with rack's `call` method:

```
put '/foo' do
  # putting related stuff
  call env.merge('REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET')
end
```